# OpenVPN can't open (Kali)

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, kali-linux, exit-code

I'm setting up an OpenVPN server on Kali. When the service is started, this error occurs:
`Job for openvpn-server@server.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status openvpn-server@server.service" and "journalctl -xeu openvpn-server@server.service" for details.`

Running journalctl, there's not much information about the error:

```
Subject: Unit process exited
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░ 
░░ An ExecStart= process belonging to unit openvpn-server@server.service has exited.
░░ 
░░ The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.
Nov 28 15:14:46 hubbles systemd[1]: openvpn-server@server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
░░ Subject: Unit failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░ 
░░ The unit openvpn-server@server.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 28 15:14:46 hubbles systemd[1]: Failed to start openvpn-server@server.service - OpenVPN service for server.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit openvpn-server@server.service has failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░ 
░░ A start job for unit openvpn-server@server.service has finished with a failure.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 164596 and the job result is failed.
```

Let me show the config file:

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
persist-key
persist-tun
keepalive 10 120
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "dchp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dchp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
dh /etc/openvpn/server/dh.pem
ecdh-curve prime256v1
ca /etc/openvpn/server/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/server/hubbles.crt
key /etc/openvpn/server/ca.key
auth SHA256
cipher AES-128-GCM
tls-server
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-cipher TLS-ECDHE-ECDSA-WITH-AES-128-GCM-SHA256
status /var/log/openvpn/status.log
verb 3
```

This exact configuration works on a friend's computer, whilst I can't run it. I had run `restorecon -Rv /etc/openvpn/` and restarted the service over, but still not luck. What am I doing wrong?

I started the whole process over and over, checked the keys are stored in the specified directory and stopped/started the service.

Comment: Try:    sudo apt-get --fix-missing update .... to get missing updates and 
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade  .....  to install new dependencies

Comment: It didn't work:
'''
┌──(qhubbles㉿hubbles)-[~]
└─$ systemctl start openvpn-server@server                               
Job for openvpn-server@server.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status openvpn-server@server.service" and "journalctl -xeu openvpn-server@server.service" for details.
                                                                                
┌──(qhubbles㉿hubbles)-[~]
└─$ 

""

Comment: If that does not work (I have successfully used this approach and I use Kali), then you may need to reinstall Kali

Comment: Does it write anything to `/var/log/openvpn/status.log`? What are the permissions on the key files?

Comment: Log's empty. Permissions, I don't know.